# Replace repeating delimiters in a text file with an alternate character

Tags: python, regex, linux

I am attempting to process a large pipe "|" delimited, double quote qualified text file (>700,000 records, >3,000 characters per record, and 28 fields per record).  using a python script.  I am encountering a problem as the csv parser is parsing fields incorrectly due to unescaped double quote characters and pipes embedded within the text of a field in the file.  Since tabs are not present in the file I would like to convert it to a tab delimited file by replacing the double-quote-pipe-double-quote delimiter/qualifier character sequence ("|") with tabs (\t).  This would be relatively straightforward if every field was populated but some are not.  Fields that are not populated are represented by a null string so I can have anywhere from 1 to 7 pipe delimiters in sequence prefaced by a double quote.

a simple example is:

```
"abc"|"2016-07-30"|"text narrative field"|"2016-08-01"|"123"|"456"|"789"|"EOR"
```

a more representative example is:

```
"abc"|"2017-01-01"|"height: 5' 7" (~180 cm) | weight: 80kg | in good health"|"2016-01-10"||||"EOR"
```

I have been attempting to write a regex that will replace each pipe character/double quote combination or sequence of pipe characters immediately preceded and followed by a double quote 1 for 1 with TAB characters.  I have found numerous regex examples for replacing a repeating string with a single character but none that replace a series of repeating characters with an equal length string of an alternate character.

I tried the following regex: `"\|{1,}"` which works for a single pipe char but replaces multiple pipes in sequence with a single TAB. I also need to handle the following related aspects:

- remove start of line/double quote (^")
- remove double quote/end of line ("$)
- and replace double quote/pipe (1 or more)/end of line (eg. "\|$) with an equal number of TAB characters as there are pipe characters

output records after application of the regex would look as follows using \t to represent TAB characters:

```
abc\t2016-07-30\ttext narrative field\t2016-08-01\t123\t456\t789\tEOR
abc\t2017-01-01\theight: 5' 7" (~180 cm) | weight: 80kg | in good health\t2016-01-10\t\t\t\tEOR
```

i am open to solving this either in python or in linux using sed or awk

Comment: *the csv parser is parsing fields incorrectly* - "Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?". If your file doesn't have valid comma separated values, it's a bit harsh to blame a csv parser for the incorrect output :P

Comment: it depends on the parser.  for example, Informatica parses the more complex record as provided above correctly.  However the csv parser, at least in my opinion, does not.  I expected that it would parse it into:
`field 1: abc`
`field 2: 2017-01-01`
`field 3: height: 5' 7" (~180 cm) | weight: 80kg | in good health`
`field 4: 2016-01-10`
...
however, it parses it into:
`field 1: abc`
`field 2: 2017-01-01`
`field 3: height: 5' 7" (~180 cm)`
`field 4: weight: 80kg`
`field 5: in good health`
`field 6: 2016-01-10`
i.e. breaks after the " even though there are other chars before the |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def count_pipes_in_regex_match(m):
  #  regex capture group should only contain pipe chars
  matched_pipes = m.groups()[0]

  return '\t' * len(matched_pipes)


# test string
s='"abc"|"2017-01-01"|"height: 5\' 7" (~180 cm) | weight: 80kg | in good health"|"2016-01-10"||||"EOR"'


# replace leading or trailing quotes
s = re.sub('^"|"$', '', s)

# replace quote pipe(s) quote 
# or      quote pipe(s) end-of-string
# with as many tabs as there were pipes
s = re.sub('"(\|+)("|$)', count_pipes_in_regex_match, s)

print repr(s) #repr to show the tabs
```

Try [online at repl.it](https://repl.it/FHCX/2)

Comment: very promptly and elegantly answered.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for `"|"` isn't the answer to replace multiple `||` with `|""|`?

how about:

```
while True:
    new_data = re.sub(r'\|\|', '|""|', data)
    if data == new_data:
        break
    data = new_data
```

After this you could then replace `"|"` with tabs.

Comment: thank you for the idea.  I don't think it will work in this case because there are multiple sequential pipes embedded in the quote qualified text field. eg. "body weight ||| needs more fluids" . fortunately there are no character sequences with double quotes immediately prefacing or following a pipe in the text field.

Comment: The fact that there are multiples is why my example has a loop.  You should try it, after my example is run, you regex looking to replace `"|"` with tabs should work just fine.

Comment: i will give it a try and post the results.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in 3 passes.

1. Replace all `||` with `|""|`
2. Split on `"|"` (and `|` on ends)
3. Remove the quotes from each field.

As follows:

```
import re

for line in file:
    while '||' in line:
        line = line.replace('||', '|""|')

    fields = re.split('^\||\|$|"\|"', line)

    new_line = '\t'.join([field.strip('"') for field in fields])
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because there are pipe(s) embedded in the double quote qualified text field, i.e. I don't want to parse a single text field with embedded pipes into separate fields.

Comment: Very true, I have updated the code to support pipes in quotes.