# Weird JSON Parsing

Tags: json

I have to load this JSON code in Python3:

```
{'code': 161, 'message': "You are unable to follow more people at this time. Learn more <a href='http://support.twitter.com/articles/66885-i-can-t-follow-people-follow-limits'>here</a>."}
```

The issue is that JSON need " and not ', so I used this line of code :

```
errorLog = json.loads(str.replace(str(error.message[0]), "'", '"'))
```

This replace all the ' by ". It's working for most of the error messages, but the one above isn't working at all, because of the ' in the link in the message.
And now i'm runing out of idea to load this JSON...

Can you figured out a solution ?

Lyxilion.

Comment: *"I have to load this JSON code in Python"* That's not [JSON](http://json.org/). If it were, you wouldn't have to replace `'` with `"`.

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605462/replace-repeating-delimiters-in-a-text-file-with-an-alternate-character Your basic issue is: "How do I replace `'` with `"` except in strings that are already in quotes?" That question shows how to do that (with `|` instead of `'`, but...).

Comment: Trying to fix the invalid JSON after you receive it cannot be anything other than painful. You should get whoever is responsible for sending your the broken data to send you valid JSON instead.

Comment: Well it's actually Twitter who broke the JSON...